# Using the pluralize helper but having the number in one div and the text in another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="votes meta engagement">
  <span class="vote-count">
    <span class="vote-total">
      <strong><%= @post.total_votes %></strong>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="vote-text secondary">votes by</span>
  <span class='voted-user'>
    <% @post.votes.each do |vote| %>
      <%= link_to vote.user.username, vote.user %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
</div>
```

I can't do `<%= pluralize(@post_total_votes, "vote") %>` because I need that text to be right before *by* in the `vote-text` div.

How can I solve this situation?

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean? why you can use this? `<span class="vote-text secondary"><%= pluralize(@post_total_votes, "vote") %> by</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this work for what you're trying to do?

```
  <span class="vote-text secondary"><%= pluralize(@post.total_votes, "vote") %> by</span>
```

edit:
Then wouldn't this work? You can obviously combine the two rails calls together, but just wanted to make sure this is what you were going for.

```
<div class="votes meta engagement">
  <span class="vote-count">
    <span class="vote-total">
      <strong><%= @post.total_votes %> <%= pluralize(@post.total_votes, "vote") %></strong>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="vote-text secondary">by</span>
  <span class='voted-user'>
    <% @post.votes.each do |vote| %>
      <%= link_to vote.user.username, vote.user %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The number will output in the vote-text div. I need it to output in the vote-total div.